# What responder catches undo action?

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller, nsundomanager

I have a view that handles undo and redo. For a specific state I change first responder from the view to the view's window. Now in that state I expect the validateMenuItem: method in the window's delegate to check the undo menu item.

This works when I close the window. But when the window is visible some other responder deals with the undo action.

My guess is that it's the window controller? But as this is a non-document based app I haven't implemented one manually. Will I have to create a custom window controller? And if so, what's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/307917-validatemenuitem-not-called-for-undo-menu-item.html

> Configuring the Undo menu item with action 'undo:' tells the
>   frameworks that this is *the* undo menu item, so it becomes one
>   element of a standard undo UI mechanism implemented in NSWindow. Under
>   these circumstances, the menu item (and especially its validation)
>   isn't yours to mess with.
>
> If you want to take implement the entire mechanism yourself, then you
>   should use a custom action such as 'myUndo:' for the Undo menu item.
>   That means, as far as the frameworks know, you app doesn't have
>   (standard) undo, and the action/validation should work in the normal
>   way.